# How can I avoid having multiple xpath variables in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, findby

i am defining 2 variables in Selenium like this:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'€11')]")
    private WebElement singleTicket;

@FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'€19')]")
    private WebElement returnTicket;`
```

i need to pass different values in these variables for different tests e.g. "$12" but i dont want to create more variables in my page object with different prices. what is a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to pass `parameter` to `@FindBy` annotation. But you can write a custom function to get `webelement` based on specific `value` and `tag` too. so you don't need to create separate element everytime. Please have a look on below function.

```
   public  WebElement getWebElementForSpecificText(String tagName, String text) {
        String formXpath= ".//"+tagName+"[contains(text(),'"+text+"')]";
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(formXpath));
    }
```

Yu can call this function as mentioned below:

```
getWebElementForSpecificText("span", "€11");
getWebElementForSpecificText("span", "€12");
getWebElementForSpecificText("span", "€19");
```